# Play framework 2.5.x Web Socket Java

Tags: java, sockets, playframework, java-websocket

I am following the instructions in the official documentation of Play framework 2.5.x to Java Websockets, I created a controller with this function

```
public static LegacyWebSocket<String> socket() {
    return WebSocket.withActor(MyWebSocketActor::props);
}
```

And an Actor class MyWebSocketActor:

```
   public class MyWebSocketActor extends UntypedActor {

    public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(MyWebSocketActor.class, out);
    }

    private final ActorRef out;

    public MyWebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            out.tell("I received your message: " + message, self());
        }
    }
}
```

Then the app is started I try to connect at ws://localhost:9000 as is written in the official documentation:

> Tip: You can test your WebSocket controller on
>   https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. Just set the location to
>   ws://localhost:9000.

But the web socket seems unreachable, how can I test it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect and not send messages or you cannot connect at all? How is your `routes` file defined? Have you looked at your developers console in your browser - what does the network tab say? You can also try creating a test client with the example on websocket.org/echo.html - so that you eliminate the cross-server scenario

Comment: I cannot connect at all and in my routes file I don't defined any route to socket method, I have to add it? When I try to connect at ws://localhost:9000 in https://www.websocket.org/echo.html in the console appear: SecurityError: The operation is insecure. If I try to check Use secure WebSocket (TLS) in the log area appear ERROR:undefined and DISCONNECTED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to  handle WebSocket connections, you also have to add a route in your `routes` file.

`GET    /ws    controllers.Application.socket()`

Then your WebSocket endpoint will be `ws://localhost:9000/ws` - use it for testing with the echo service.

Comment: Thank you Anton, I followed your suggestion, but when I go to `http://localhost:9000/ws` I get this message _Upgrade to WebSocket required_. And I don't able to connect to the web socket from http://websocket.org/echo.html . I don't understand why it is so difficult to create a websocket in Play. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Finally I solved it, remove static from socket() method and add endpoint to it, as suggest Anton, in routes file, then start the application with SSL/TLS, for example, activator run -Dhttps.port=9443, at this point insert wss://localhost:9443/ws in Location field on https://websocket.org/echo.html and it connects to the web socket.

Comment: `wss` is the WebSocket Secure protocol. You don't need to use it if you don't want to, you can still use only `ws`. You see the `Upgrade to WebSocket required` because you try to connect to the WebSocket endpoint directly with your browser - but instead you have to do it from some client - for example written in JavaScript (as the echo service) or some other service.

Answer (score 2):

Finally with the help of Anton I solved it!
First: remove static from socket() method

```
public LegacyWebSocket<String> socket() {
        return WebSocket.withActor(MyWebSocketActor::props);
    }
```

Then add an endpoint in routes file for the socket() method

```
GET     /ws                          controllers.HomeController.socket()
```

At this point you have to start the application with SSL/TLS in this way, for example:

```
activator run -Dhttps.port=9443
```

In [websocket.org/echo.html](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) insert `wss://localhost:9443/ws` in Location field and it connects to websocket!

Furthermore if I visit `https://localhost:9443/ws` I continue to obtain the message

> Upgrade to WebSocket required

Comment: Just an info regarding the removal of `static`: this is the way to go in Play 2.4, Play 2.5 and for the future - part of the idea to remove global state and use dependency injection